# How to perform proper cross-validation in case of a regime shift?

Tags: regression, cross-validation

Assume that K-Fold cross validation is used on time series and the data experiences a regime shift after the 1st fold (assume it is the leftmost one for simplicity). Regime shift in this context means that the model is not appropriate (performs badly) in-sample after the regime change. We apply a fix to the model by training it on adjusted data (changing the target), so the model works fine after the shift. However, that fix only works in the time series context. Within K-Fold CV it is still possible that the model is trained on updated target from k-1 splits (rightmost) and then tested on the 1st split (leftmost) with the old target which will apparently show bad metrics.
In this case what would be the best way to account for a regime shift ? Run K-Fold twice: once before and once after the shift ?